# PythonException: 'TypeError: field timestamp: TimestampType can not accept object 161.657471 in type <class 'float'>'. Full traceback below:

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm creating a dataframe with a schema defined and rdd of the dataframe below.

results_df

| job_id | tag_name | timestamp | avg_tag_value | result | created_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | tag_1 | 2023-02-15T21:45:00.000+0000 | 4714.259 | 234.1 | 2023-02-15T22:34:58.000+0000 |
| A | tag_2 | 2023-02-15T21:45:00.000+0000 | 4231.234 | 342.2 | 2023-02-15T22:34:58.000+0000 |
| A | tag_3 | 2023-02-15T21:45:00.000+0000 | 4325.2 | 124.2 | 2023-02-15T22:34:58.000+0000 |
| A | tag_4 | 2023-02-15T21:45:00.000+0000 | 5362.3 | 535.2 | 2023-02-15T22:34:58.000+0000 |

```
  schema = StructType(
            [
                StructField('job_id', StringType(), False),
                StructField('tag_name', StringType(), False),
                StructField('timestamp', TimestampType(), False),
                StructField('avg_tag_value', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('result', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('created_time', TimestampType(), False),
            ]
        )
        _df_to_save = self.spark.createDataFrame(
            custom_ml.results_df.rdd,
            schema,
        )
```

And I'm getting this error below when trying to print out a dataframe

```
_df_to_save.display()

PythonException: 'TypeError: field timestamp: TimestampType can not accept object 161.657471 in type <class 'float'>'. Full traceback below:
```

could anyone help me out here?

would much appreciate any help!

Comment: include a code snippet that replicates the error

Comment: The error is obvious, there might be the currupted data.

Comment: I think we get an issue when converting it to RDD... there is no currupted data for timestamp column. Jus wondering what happens when the timestamp value is converted to RDD